# Accessing IE Touch from a Laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen, internet-explorer-11

Even though my Dell XPS 12 has a tablet mode, it seems as though only the desktop version of Internet Explorer can be found. Is there a way to access the touch version of Internet Explorer from a laptop that seemingly doesn't support it? If so, how?

Comment: You have to start the modern version of IE11.  This can only be done from the Start Screen.  **Its not possible for it NOT to exist.**

Comment: @Ramhound When I search for Internet Explorer from the Start Menu, I only see one Internet Explorer icon, which launches the desktop version. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: `Windows 8.1` does not have a `Start Menu` it has a `Start Screen`. IE11 also must be the default browser for the modern version of IE11 to be launched.  If IE11 is not the default browser then the modern version of IE11 cannot be launched.  Only the default browser can be launched in the "Modern UI" mode, Firefox and Chrome, have both basically cancelled their Modern/Touch Windows 8 versions.

Comment: @Ramhound That's exactly the answer I was looking for. If you post it as an answer I will be sure to accept it.